# JS Make function object return

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I am creating a function object. However when I run this object it returns undefined.
For instance, in this [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/T8e7g/1/), when I try `alert(test(8))`, the function runs and returns 13 but when I create a Function object, 'alert(func(8))' returns undefined.

```
<button onclick="start()">Start Test</button>

<script>

    function test(num) {
        alert("running...");
        return num + 5;
    }

    function start(){
        alert(test(8));

        var func = new Function("num", "test(num)");
        alert(func(8)); 
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in your second `func`, you are not `return`ing the value of `test(num)`

```js
function test(num) {
  alert("running...");
  return parseInt(num) + 5;
}

function start(){
  alert(test(8));

  // return the value obtained on calling test(num)     <------------
  var func = new Function("num", "return test(num)");
  alert(func(8));
}

start();
```

Comment: @NevilleNazerane Ok, nice you did. Could you please accept my answer if it helped. Thank you!

Comment: Well frankly I found out the exact same solution before looking at your answer. However even thought it did not help it was perfect. I will accept it as far as stackoverflow allows me to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. When I checked the value of the variable func in the console I found I would need to return the function like [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T8e7g/2/). I needed to use `var func = new Function("num", "return test(num)")` instead of `var func = new Function("num", "test(num)")`